# how to check if an Isolate is killed?

Tags: flutter, dart

The Isolate class (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) doesn't seem to have any properties indicating if it has been killed.

Comment: tried https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/addOnExitListener.html?